# Composer says package of lower version is required in certain contexts. (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I have a drupal profile called "orange_profile". It requires a bunch of common modules and requires drupal 9. If I go into the profile and run `composer update` it installs all the modules and core with proper versions (all beta or stable). Running `composer depends drupal/core` I can see that nothing is stuck below drupal 9.

But when I go to an actual site and try to install the profile it errors stating that the profile requires drupal `~8.0`. I cannot get this to change.

Here is the error output:

```
composer require drupal/orange_profile:dev-2.0.x
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update drupal/orange_profile
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/orange_profile dev-2.0.x -> satisfiable by drupal/orange_profile[dev-2.0.x].
    - drupal/orange_profile dev-2.0.x requires drupal/core ~8.0 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.1).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Using `-W` does not help. In fact it sometimes still suggests that I use `-W` when I am using it.

Here are the composer.jsons:

Orange Profile

```
{
  "name": "drupal/orange_profile",
  "type": "drupal-profile",
  "description": "Drupal Orange install profile with common modules.",
  "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/orange_profile",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.0",
    "drupal/advagg": "^4.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^5.0",
    "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.0",
    "drupal/ckeditor_media_embed": "^1.6",
    "drupal/coffee": "^1.0",
    "drupal/color_field": "^2.0",
    "drupal/colorbutton": "^1.1",
    "drupal/comments_order": "^1.1",
    "drupal/config_inspector": "^1.0",
    "drupal/core": "^9.1",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^1.12",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^1.4",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.2",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.5",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
    "drupal/google_tag": "^1.2",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
    "drupal/hotjar": "^2.0",
    "drupal/image_effects": "^3.0",
    "drupal/imce": "^2.3",
    "drupal/linkit": "^6.0",
    "drupal/magnific_popup": "^1.4",
    "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.1",
    "drupal/menu_block": "^1.5",
    "drupal/menu_trail_by_path": "^1.1",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.5",
    "drupal/orange_starter": "2.0.x-dev",
    "drupal/panelbutton": "^1.1",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.3",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.2",
    "drupal/schema_metatag": "^1.4",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.8",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.1",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.8",
    "drupal/swiftmailer": "^2.0",
    "drupal/token": "^1.3",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.0",
    "drupal/userprotect": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.5",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.0"
  }
}
```

The site

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../orange_profile",
            "options": {
                "symlink": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "^9.1"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        }
    }
}
```

This shows me trying to install just the core package and using a local version of the orange profile but the same happens when I am using the one from  the remote repo and core-recommended.

My only hunch is that there is some dependencie down the way which has an odd requirement for something like doctrine as I have seen composer telling me that it's because the core `8.0.0-beta6` requires a specific commit of doctrine. This error appeared a couple times.

Anyone seen similar? I noticed while googling that others got the same or similar errors when trying to install certain modules like `drupal/entity`.

And one more side note, why can I only see what a package requires when it is installed? It would be more convenient for something like this to see the specific requirements of the profile that are asking for a lower core version.

Comment: Could it work after calling `composer clearcache`?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and it has not helped. Others I'm working with get the same errors.